# git http push via WebDAV - what if my username has an "@" in it?

Tags: git, webdav, git-push

My web hosting provider lets me access my webspace via WebDAV, so I thought I'd set up a git repository over there just to see what happens.  Cloning the repository read-only works just fine, as "git clone http://my.server.com/repo.git" just uses the standard HTTP transport.

Problems arise when I try to use WebDAV, because my user id is "user@my.server.com" and I have to use port 2077.  This means I have to do something like

```
git config remote.origin.pushurl http://user@my.server.com@my.server.com:2077/repo.git
```

and the two @ signs in the URL must be causing problems because "git push origin master" reports "error 22".

I tried creating a .netrc file entry

```
machine    my.server.com
login      user@my.server.com
password   ****
```

but that didn't seem to help.

I've also tried replacing the first "@" with a "%", "\@" and "%40" but none of those worked.

Comment: I was wondering if you ever came up with a solution to this issue, as I am experiencing the problem, and I recognize the ports... I'm at the same provider.

Answer (score 6):

The current version of git doesn't handle percent-unescaping in username and password. I submitted a patch yesterday to fix this (at least for HTTP URLs) so it might be fixed soon. With the patch, you should be able to access the WebDAV with:

git config remote.origin.pushurl http://user%40my.server.com@my.server.com:2077/repo.git

However you may have another problem related to an issue with libcurl > 7.16 (see the note in "git help http-push") at the time I'm writing.

Answer (score 1):

If the URI used by WebDAV does follow the [Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.html) ([rfc3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)), there should not be any `@` in the `userinfo`

```
 authority     = [ userinfo "@" ] host [ ":" port ]
 userinfo      = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" )
 pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG

 unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
 sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
               / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="


 reserved      = gen-delims / sub-delims
 gen-delims    = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
```

So did you try just with `http://user@my.server.com:2077/repo.git`?

Comment: I tried dav://user@my.server.com:2077/ on my Ubuntu laptop before I got anywhere near Git.  It didn't work, and took several fruitless hours to discover that I needed dav://my.server.com:2077/, then enter user@my.server.com and password when prompted.  Whoever wrote that bit of cPanel-11 (used by my hosting provider) obviously wasn't thinking about RFC-compliant usernames :-(

Comment: So my question actually has nothing to do with Git.  The WebDAV implementation on my server uses usernames that don't comform to RFC 3986, so unless it supports a replacement character for "@" then I'm stuffed!

Comment: @kbro I am afraid it starts to look that way... And I do not know about any replacement for the at sign in an id username.

Comment: I tried every one you listed in sub-delims, and most of gen-delims too.  No joy.  I've asked my webhost provider to get onto the cPanel developers to report the problem.

Comment: @kbro: sorry it has to come to that. I hope they will find some kind of solution or workaround.